# Installing ESXi 6.7 on HP Gen9 Warning vmFileSystem: Slow refresh failed. Cannot open volume: vmfs/volumes/

Tags: vmware-esxi, installation, hp, datastore

Durin installation of ESXi 6.7 (HPE Custom ISO) on HPE Gen9 server I see this message:

[image]

And it is stuck on this "Scanning System":

> Gathering additional system information. This may take a few moments.

Could u help me about the problem.

Comment: Does your machine have one (or more) FC adapters?

Comment: 2 FC Adapters I have.

Comment: Now it starting installation but the process is slow going. But the warning still on the screen. In addition, this vmfs path related a VM which is not open console/RDP or not changing state (power off, shut down).

Answer (score 1):

This is known ... thing ... in the ESXi installer from 6.0 on. Disconnect (physically remove) the FC cables (just leave them open for a few minutes) and setup will continue. After finishing setup, put the ports back in and everything will work like nothing happend.

I once tried to find the "real" answer and got stuck somewhere between something like "the FC loop discontinue id should be set to false when the WWN ends of 4E prior to setup when using QLogic switches" and "something in your FC setup is not right but we can't lay a finger on it". I have no idea - even zoning both ports out complete didn't resolve this for me, so I just kept doing the "plug it back in after its done" game. Hint: This was a tip from vmware support. And it worked well for me.

Pro-Tip: Check the error console <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> for errors during setup.

Comment: Cool. I had no idea.